# My text is aligned to the left when you put the mouse. How to prevent this displacement in css

Tags: html, css

I have my search bar which displays recent searches when you put the mouse on a search the text moves to the left. how to remove this movement on left to keep him fixe

```
.search-active{
      background: rgb(154, 154, 156) !important;
     
      margin: 0px;
      
      
}
```

Comment: can you share your html code as well?

Comment: You're setting margin to 0, so I assume whatever this class is added to has a margin that you're overwriting.

Comment: Whenever possible, you need to include a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue. You can also include the expected behavior, the actual behavior, and how they differ, that would be helpful as well. Please visit [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Check for any events like :hover , :focus , :active , and toggle them in Inspector. If you are using bootstrap or something it may have their own event css that u need to change.